# Which site template do I use for SP2013 site for my requirement?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, site-template

We are developing using SharePoint 2013. We need to have document library to publish excel files that can be then viewed via Excel Web Services webpart. We need to plan out the site and need advice on the same.

We have Customers and customers have Clients. There will be a site collection with light branding. Then, we need to have a subsite for each customer, with custom branding for each subsite, and this should be the landing page for clients of that customer.

I was wondering whether we need to use team site template/publishing site or whether there is any other template that would better serve such scenario and how to go about?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like the team site template would be an ideal starting point for the sites.

You could modify the team site by adding / removing any web parts that you would like for your customers and clients and then save them as a site template.  This creates a WSP file and adds your site to the "custom" tab in the new site dialog.

You may want to consider having each customer as a site collection to ensure security (for example to separate search results so one customer cannot see another's data) and administration.